# What does the value tag do in raw JSON text format?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The `value` component was recently introduced. What does it do?

```
tellraw @p {"rawtext":[{"score":["name":"name_ph","objective":"obj_ph","value":"value_ph"]}]}?
```

Answer (score 1):

As clearly stated by the Minecraft Wiki, which should be the first place you research to find this info:

> `value`: Optional. If present, this value is displayed regardless of what the score would have been.

This feature is actually a remnant from older versions of the game. This `value` tag is what older score components were resolved to, instead of a `text` component. It's no longer used though. You can if you want to, but there isn't really a point anymore.

---

P.S. Your syntax is wrong, the square brackets surrounding `score` and its stuff should be curly braces `{}` instead:

```
tellraw @p {"rawtext":[{"score":{"name":"name_ph","objective":"obj_ph","value":"value_ph"}}]}?
```

Comment: I know about the brace other than brackets thing, I just typed it in a minute so I didn't think about it, but I found the wiki on Fandom to be very vague and cannot find what it actually does, if **value** could be used for anything useful at all.

Comment: @ZappyNE It's pointless.